# Running a loop of a function multiple times

Tags: python, function, loops

I have code to plot particle trajectories until all the spaces in a portion of a 3D matrix are filled. This is based on the final position of the particle. A simplified simulation of particles in a beam of radiation traveling through a body.

I was able to use a for loop to plot a whole bunch of particle trajectories together, and to get the number it takes to fill up all the spaces. I did this by, 
'''

```
n = 100
for n in range(particles):
    Path(ax,body)
    if body==[[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]:
        print('Tumor destroyed after particle number', n)
        break
plt.show()
```

'''

and I get the number of particles (n). But I want to loop this many times and then get an average of the number (n) it takes to fill all the spaces in the matrix (destroy the tumor). I tried doing '''

```
trials=10
for i in range(trials): 
    for n in range(particles):
        Path(ax,body)
        if body==[[[0 for k in range(10)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]:
            print('Tumor destroyed after particle number', n)
            break
```

'''
but i just get the same n value from the first part of code 10 times. How do I get it to do the first bit of code new each time and get different n values to average them.

EDIT
The numbers should all be different since I am using random numbers for the calculations. The calculations are being done inside the Path function. I just want to runt the first snipet of code multiple times and am not sure how to execute it. I can add the full code, but it is very long.

Comment: I am guessing you will have to generate new `particles` and probably `ax` and `body` for each trial, but you will have to give us more information... I mean, if you run the same inputs 10 times, of course you will get the same output 10 times

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Does your simulation use some randomized initial conditions? If so, you probably need to use random.seed() during each trial.
If your simulation is completely deterministic, you should expect the same result every time for the same initial conditions.

Comment: I only have the code here that loops the function, within the path function there are a lot of different calculations using different random numbers.